# Are there official church structures that exist under a Parish in the Catholic Church?

Tags: catholicism, church-local, subsidiarity, catholic-parishes

Our diocese recently had a big re-org and went down from over 100 parishes down to 30. But now our cozy little ex-congregation can't do anything fun unless the big mega-church ladies say so or we beg our pastor.  Given the principle of subsidiarity, are there any lay-structures that exist, or have existed in the past, to allow some level of self-governance in parish life?

We'd like to be able to organize our own men's and women's slightly-larger-than small groups, youth activities, dances, novenas, non-Eucharistic processions (like the seven-churches visitation)

I think there would still be a point person who would go to the priest for approval, where necessary, but we could avoid the hassle of being vetoed by church ladies and the stress of being lone wolves trying to organize things in vacuums.

Comment: It's hard to say without elaborating on the details. Could you elaborate on what types of things your "ex-congregation" wants to do?

Comment: @eques sure - the impetus of this question is because I'm trying to organize a simple walk between two churches on Holy Thursday night, which we did for the two years before the merger (when we had four churches with altars of repose) and it's super hard to get something remotely advertised by the parish. And if it doesn't look organized, people think you're "up to something" and if it isn't advertised people think you left them out. So there's really no winning without subsidiarity.

Answer (score 2):

In general, yes, it is very much possible to organize as laity. If you want to see the legal side, try book II of canon law. There may also be some country specific rules. In my country, just as an example, any legal entity under canon law is recognized as a legal entity under civil law. SO you can found a foundation or an association by church, with the same legal status as when it were founded by civil means.

In my country it is absolutely normal to find lots of catholic associations within a parish, with only limited influence by the parish

Answer (score 2):

**Are there official church structures that exist under a Parish in the Catholic Church?**

Unfortunately there seem to be no set of ecclesiastical norms that exist in the present state of affairs regarding setting up some sort of pius activities nowadays.

However, Catholic laypersons are still free to set or try to set up some sort of Catholic pious custom at the parish level.

It is unfortunate that in our day, parish priests are not conducive to helping out, in part because they have very busy schedules. Of which, I do not wholly agree with.

One of the biggest obstacles that I have encountered is that parish councils tend to make the rules on almost everything. This is one of my greatest pet peeves about these so-called parish councils, which nowadays could be be completely filled up with one one type of Catholic association such as the CWL. It is so unfortunate that pastors almost always listen to their parish councils and even allow some decisions to go to a vote.

Parish councils are to give advice to their parish priests and not make the rules. Unfortunately pastors often will not go against the parish councils. In the long run they call the shots and pastors go along with this. This is very wide spread in parish-life where I live and it sucks.

> [**Parish Council**](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=35407&randomterm=false)
>
> Modelled on the diocesan council, a group of parishioners organized to co-operate with the pastor in the apostolic work of a parish. After describing the functions of diocesan councils the Second Vatican Council decreed that "Such councils should also be found, if possible, at parochial, inter-parochial and inter-diocesan levels, and also on the national and international plane" (decree Apostolicam Actuositatem, 26). **As conceived by the Church, parish councils are merely advisory to the pastor and are meant to assist him.** Unlike their counterparts among Protestants, a Catholic parish council does not operate under the trustee system. It does not either replace the authority of the pastor or make him juridically dependent on its decision.

In the end you could try to set up some sort of Catholic guild or Catholic association, while not going so far a creating a **Catholic confraternity**, which might require that one obtain permission from the local ordinary (bishop).

> A confraternity or sodality is a voluntary association of the faithful, established and guided by competent ecclesiastical authority for the promotion of special works of Christian charity or piety. The name is sometimes applied to pious unions, but the latter differ from confraternities inasmuch as they need not be canonically erected and they regard rather the good of the neighbour than the personal sanctification of the members. Confraternities are divided into those properly so called and those to which the name has been extended. Both are erected by canonical authority, but the former have a more precise organization, with rights and duties regulated by ecclesiastical law, and their members often wear a peculiar costume and recite the Office in common. When a confraternity has received the authority to aggregate to itself sodalities erected in other localities and to communicate its advantages to them, it is called an archconfraternity.
>
> Pious associations of laymen existed in very ancient times at Constantinople and Alexandria. In France, in the eighth and ninth centuries, the laws of the Carlovingians mention confraternities and guilds. But the first confraternity in the modern and proper sense of the word is said to have been founded at Paris by Bishop Odo who died in 1208. It was under the invocation of the Blessed Virgin Mary. Various other congregations, as of the Gonfalon, of the Holy Trinity, of the Scapular, etc., were founded between the thirteenth and sixteenth centuries. From the latter century onwards, these pious associations have multiplied greatly. Indulgences are communicated to confraternities either directly by the pope or through the bishops, unless the association be aggregated to an archconfraternity (it may not be aggregated to more than one) through which it participates in the latter's privilege. If the aggregation be not made according to the prescribed formula, the Indulgences are not communicated. The directors of confraternities are appointed or approved by the bishop, or in the churches of regulars by the regular superior. Only after such appointment can the director apply the Indulgences to the objects which he blesses, and he cannot subdelegate this power without special faculty. The reception of members must be carried out by the appointed person. The observance of the rules is not binding in conscience nor does their neglect deprive a person of membership, though in the latter case the Indulgences would not be obtained. The loss of all its members for a short time does not dissolve a confraternity, and by the reception of new members the Indulgences may again be gained. The dissolution, translation, and visitation of confraternities belong to the ordinary. The canon law governing these associations is found in the Constitution of Clement VIII (7 Dec., 1604) with some modification made later by the Sacred Congregation of Indulgences. - [Confraternity (Sodality)](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/04223a.htm)

It is so hard to organize some Catholic exterior customs in our times that I would venture to say that you just do itand hope for the best. If it becomes popular, changes are it could become a local Catholic custom in your region.

Believe me when I say that I know how you fell. I have been stonewalled many times.

Good luck and do not get discouraged. Pax!